# Setting yaxis labels in log plot using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to set customized labels in a log plot using

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
plt.yscale('log')
plt.ylim([1,30])
ax = plt.axes()
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.FixedLocator([1,10]))
plt.legend(loc=0, fontsize="17")
plt.show()
```

but it only allows me to set labels at 1 or 10, not in between. Is there another setting I need to change?

Comment: Maybe you want to use a `plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.ScalarFormatter())`? Or do you want just any custom ticks, like `plt.yticks([1,3,6,10], ["A", "B", 900, "Auto"])`?

Comment: yes that works... thanks a lot